# unexpected output for sorting in python

Tags: python-2.7

This is the program for bubble sort. It is not displaying the correct output. I don't understand why.

```
numbers = input("enter nos.: ")
my_list = list(numbers)

def bubble(list):
    length = len(list) - 1
    sorted = False

    while sorted == False:
        for i in range(length):
            if list[i] > list[i+1]:
                sorted = False
                list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
        sorted = True
bubble(my_list)
print "Sorted list is: ",my_list
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter nos.: 1,454,867,43,421,0,8,43,121,45656,76,4,34,1
Sorted list is:  [1, 454, 43, 421, 0, 8, 43, 121, 867, 76, 4, 34, 1, 45656]
```

Answer (score 0):

your while loop will terminate after a single pass because sorted is always set to true. try putting that statement before your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found your problem : the While loop is only executed once.

Your While condition is `sorted == False`, and you set `sorted = False` if you do an inversion. You have to change that :

```
numbers = input("enter nos.: ")
my_list = list(numbers)

def bubble(list):
    length = len(list) - 1
    sorted = True

    while sorted == True:
        sorted = False
        for i in range(length):
            if list[i] > list[i+1]:
                list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
                sorted = True

bubble(my_list)
print "Sorted list is: ",my_list
```